# Using a method inside an other method ofe Main method

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I am trying to use a method inside an other method that belongs to Main section. Everything is ok but when I try to do it with dynamic method, I cannot reach the method. but with static it is ok.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c1 = new Car("Person1", 120, 10);
            //string message = OnCarEngineEvent
            c1.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent)); // here I cannot reach the method OnCarEngineEvent
            //c1.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));  we can use this instead of Car.CarEngineHandler handler1 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                c1.Accelerate(10);
            }
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public  void OnCarEngineEvent(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Car Object");
            Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", msg);
            Console.WriteLine("*************************");
        }
    }
    class Car
    {
        public int MaxSp { get; set; } 
        public int CurrSp { get; set; }
        public string PetName { get; set; }
        public Car()
        {

        }

        public Car(string petName, int maxSp, int currSp)
        {
            MaxSp = maxSp;
            CurrSp = currSp;
            PetName = petName;

        }

        public bool CarIsDead { get; set; }

        public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string message);

        private CarEngineHandler listOfCarHandlers;

        public void RegisterWithCarEngine (CarEngineHandler messageToMethod)
        {
            listOfCarHandlers = messageToMethod;
        }

        public void Accelerate(int baseSpeed)
        {
            if (CarIsDead)
            {
                if (listOfCarHandlers != null)
                    listOfCarHandlers("Sorry but car is dead");
            }

            else
            {
                CurrSp += baseSpeed;
                if (10 == (MaxSp - CurrSp) && listOfCarHandlers != null)
                {
                    listOfCarHandlers("Careful, you gonna blow!");
                }
                if (CurrSp > MaxSp)
                {
                    CarIsDead = true;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Current Speed is {0}", CurrSp);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I set OnCarEngineEvent as static, program works. But if I type it like " public void OnCarEngineEvent(string msg)"  then I cannot reach the method in the case of calling delegate.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why you cannot pass the non-static method as a parameter to RegisterWithCarEngine, it's necessary to understand the difference between static and non-static functions:

- non-static functions live in an object. They can access all the
  members of that object. For example, Accelerate can use MaxSp. If
  there are two cars with different maximum speeds, the function will
  behave differently depending on which car you call it on.
- Static functions are on their one. They aren't part of any object
  (even though they are in classes), so they cannot access any members.
  If you have a static function in car, it cannot access MaxSp because
  there might be multiple cars with different speeds. The static
  function won't know which MaxSp to choose. Static functions can, or
  course, access other static functions and members of static objects.

So why can't you pass a non-static function to RegisterWithCarEngine? The main method is static, so you are not in any instance of Program. If you pass a non-static function to RegisterWithCarEngine, that non-static function might access non-static members of Program (even though there aren't any of those). In that case, the compiler would not know which instance of use. So you have to mark your function as static to tell the compiler "I won't access any non-static members of this class".

If you did the things in your main method in a different method that is non-static, you could pass a non-static function to RegisterWithCarEngine.